# Euler 14 - Runtime too long (Not really duplicate, I didn't understand how to solve it from similar answer)

Tags: java

So I'm solving [Question #14 on ProjectEuler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) and my code's output is not coming out. The method is good, if I use the example from the website I get the same result BUT I think I get stuck in loop, I don't get a result even if I use a number like "3" or "4" not 1,000,000. What I'm doing wrong? I tried to understand the last question and I didn't really get much with that cache stuff.Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class problem_14 {
// n->n/2 (even)
// n->3n+1(odd)
static long max=0;
static long counter = 0;
//Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

public static long dochain(long n){
    while(n!=1){
    if(n%2==0){
        n=n/2;
        counter++;
    }
    else {
        n=(3*n)+1;
        counter++;
    }
}
    counter++;
    return counter;
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    long chain=0;;
    long nr=0;
    for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++){
        chain = dochain(i);
        if (chain>max){
            max = chain;
            nr = i;
        }
        System.out.println("nr="+nr+" lungime="+max);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What is Euler #14? Please describe in full what you're trying to do, what problem you're having, and what steps you've taken to solve the issue?

Comment: It's Project Euler, problem number 14. Here is how it sounds: http://i.gyazo.com/e814ca010c9449d698fc94b6992bb609.png

Comment: Me, and a bunch of other SO users, can't follow links like that. Also, on SO, questions should be self-contained and not reliant on external resources that may disapear in the future. If you don't have the energy to ask the question, then I doubt if anyone will have the energy to answer you.

Comment: I have edited the question with a link to the original problem and not a screenshot.

Comment: It looks like you need to reset counter to 0 after each iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dochain()` method goes into an infinite loop if you give it a 0.

```
    while (n != 1) {
        if (n % 2 == 0) { // true for n == 0
            n = n / 2; // n is still 0
            counter++;
        } else {
            n = (3 * n) + 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

You are checking if it's divisible by 2, which it is, then dividing by 2, which leaves n == 0 and looping forever.

Since your main for loop starts at 0...

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem along with my counter which was reset to 0 after every itineration. Thank you too @James

Answer (score 0):

You are starting your for loop from i = 0 which is causing dochain() to run infinitely.

Start from i =1.